# what does threading mean when it comes to programming?

Tags: php, multithreading

i read somewhere that php has threading ability called pcntl_fork(). but i still dont get what it means? whats its purpose?

software languages have multithreading abilities from what i understand, correct me if im wrong, that its the ability for a parent object to have children of somekind.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

From wikipedia: "In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest unit of processing that can be scheduled by an operating system. It generally results from a fork of a computer program into two or more concurrently running tasks."

Basically, having threads is having the ability to do multiple things within the same running application (or, process space as said by RC).

For example, if you're writing a chat server app in PHP, it would be really nice to "fork" certain tasks so if the server gets hung up processing something like a file transfer or very slow client it can spawn a thread to take care of the file transfer while the main application continues to transfer messages between clients without delay. Last time I'd used PHP, the threading was clunky/not very well supported.

Or, on the client end, while sending said file, it would be a good idea to thread the file transfer, otherwise you wouldn't be able to send messages to the server while sending the file.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a very good metaphor. Think of a thread like a worker or helper that will do work or execute code for you in the background while your program could possibly be doing other tasks such as taking user input.

Comment: a cron job is more like a program that gets run on a schedule.  Threaded programming is more along the lines of a program that's doing a couple of things at once.

Answer (score 1):

Threading means you can have more than one line of execution within the same process space.  Note that this is different than a multi-process paradigm as processes will not share the same memory space.

This [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) will do a good job getting you up to speed with threads.  Having said that, the function `pcntl_fork()` in PHP, appears to create a child process which falls inline with the multi-process paradigm.

In layman's terms, since a thread gives you more than one line of execution within a program, it allows you to do more than one thing at the same time.  Technically, you're not always doing these things simultaneously as in a single core processor, you're really just time-slicing so it appears you're doing more than one thing at a time.

A pretty straight-forward use of threads is how connections to a web server are handled.  If you didn't have multiple threads, your application would listen for a connection on a socket, accept the connection when a client requested a connection, and then would process whatever page the client asked for.  This seems well and good until you have a page that takes 5 seconds to load and you have 2 clients connecting at the same time.  One of the clients will sit and wait for the server to accept their connection for ~5 seconds, because the 1st client is using the only line of execution to serve the page and it can't do that and accept the 2nd connection.

Now if you have multiple threads, you'll have one thread (i.e. the listener thread) that only accepts connections.  As soon as the connection is accepted by the listener thread, he will pass the connection on to another thread.  We'll call it the processor thread.  Once the connection is passed on to the processor thread, the listener thread will immediately go back to waiting for a new connection.  Meanwhile, the processor thread will use it's own execution line to serve the page that takes 5 seconds.  In the scenario above, the 2nd client would have it's connection accepted immediately after the 1st client was handed to the 1st processor thread and an additional 2nd processor thread would be created to handle the request from the 2nd client.  This would typically allow you to serve both clients the data in a little over 5 seconds while the single-threaded app would take ~10 seconds.

Hope this helps with your understanding of application threading.

Answer (score -2):

**Threading** mean not to allow sequential behavior inside your code, whatever is your programming language..

Comment: It's more about allowing multiple paths of sequential behaviour at a time